# Why SpringApplication returns 0 in getExitCodeFromMappedException when ApplicationContext is inactive

Tags: spring-boot

I run a spring-boot application, it throws exception during bean creation in main thread due to some evironment problems. It does not exit as what I thought.

I looked up the source code to find out why is happened.

It is in method `getExitCodeFromMappedException`  of `SpringApplication`

It returns 0 when ApplicationContext is inactive

In my application the Exception is ApplicationContexException, an instance of BeansException

causing the invocation of `cancelRefesh` of `AbstractApplicationContext` which set active false.

I wonder why `getExitCodeFromMappedException`  returns 0 instead of other value when ApplicationContext is inactive.

Finally, I caught the exception in my code and force exit my application.
but I still wonder why `getExitCodeFromMappedException`  returns 0 instead of other value when ApplicationContext is inactive.